# How do I repair a sewage leak in a wall?

Tags: plumbing, cinderblock

My kitchen sink sewage pipe has a leak behind the cinder block wall. Couldn't get a clear picture of the exact leaking spot, but it's at least several inches inside. I'm trying to find a plumber, but they are all crazy busy. The main challenge I see is to access the leak. The fix is perhaps not hard.

- Would it be safe to remove some cinder blocks? As far as I can see, they are not bearing the load.
- Do you have other suggestions?
- What tools work best for this job?

[image]

Comment: Is there a crawl space behind there or something? Why not just go to the other side of the wall? And technically it's bad to have your copper pipe touching the galvanized duct. With water or even condensation on the waterline, there will be corrosion where they touch. Just the duct, though.

Comment: Also **very** bad to have copper touching concrete, a likely caue of the leak, even.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to have axcess to the other side of the wall. What is on the other side? If it goes into the ground it looks like digging is in your future.

The copper drain will need to be cut out and removed. It's best if it is replaced with PVC.

As popham stated the galvanized metal duct and concrete block add to the likel y hood of corrosion of the copper. ( probably the cause of the leak.)  While work is done add something like pipe wrap or similar to insulate the copper from contact with the block and dissimilar metals.

Comment: The other side is another room. The pipe probably goes above the ceiling of that room.